# Regex text between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract data fields from PDF texts using regex.

The text is:

> `"SAMPLE EXPERIAN CUSTOMER\n2288150 - EXPERIAN SAMPLE REPORTS\nData Dictionary Report\nFiltered By:\nCustom Selection\nMarketing Element:\nPage 1 of 284\n2014-11-11 21:52:01 PM\nExperian and the marks used herein are service marks or registered trademarks of Experian.\n© Experian 2014 All rights reserved. Confidential and proprietary.\n**Data Dictionary**\nDate of Birth is acquired from public and proprietary files. These sources provide, at a minimum, the year of birth; the month is provided where available. Exact date of birth at various levels of detail is available for \n\n\n\n\n\nNOTE: Records coded with DOB are exclusive of Estimated Age (101E)\n**Element Number**\n0100\nDescription\nDate Of Birth / Exact Age\n**Data Dictionary**\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFiller, three bytes\n**Element Number**\n0000\n**Description**\nEnhancement Mandatory Append\n**Data Dictionary**\n\n\nWhen there is insufficient data to match a customer's record to our enrichment master for estimated age, a median estimated age based on the ages of all other adult individuals in the same ZIP+4 area is provided. \n\n\n\n\n\n\n00 = Unknown\n**Element Number**\n0101E\n**Description**\nEstimated Age\n"`

The field names are in bold. The texts between field names are the field values.

The first time I tried to extract the 'Description' field using the following regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('\nDescription\n(.*?)\nData Dictionary\n')
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

The results are correct:

```
['Date Of Birth / Exact Age', 'Enhancement Mandatory Append']
```

But using the same idea to extract 'Data Dictionary' Field gives the empty result:

```
pattern = re.compile('\nData Dictionary\n(.*?)\nElement Number\n')
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Results:

```
[]
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You might want to use raw strings to define your pattern, by the way (e.g. `re.compile(r'\nDescription...`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` doesn't match newlines by default. Try:

```
pattern = re.compile('\nData Dictionary\n(.*?)\nElement Number\n', flags=re.DOTALL)
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Notice how I passed [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) as the `flags` argument to [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the flag `re.MULTILINE` in your regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('\nData Dictionary\n(.*?)\nElement Number\n', re.MULTILINE)
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Comment: Using multiline mode, you might also just remove all the explicit `\n` and just use the two delimiting patterns as boundaries: `'Data Dictionary\n(.*?)\nElement Number'`

Comment: Yours also work. Unfortunately I can only accept the earliest answer...but thanks very much.

Comment: @user2517984 if you like it, you can give it a +1 ;)

Comment: I wish I could, but I need to have 15 reputaion to vote . Will get back to this after getting extra reputations.

Comment: I wanted to get "APPLICATION_NAME, ROLE_ID" from the following text PRIMARY KEY
  (APPLICATION_NAME, ROLE_ID)
  USING INDEX APP_ROLES.SWR_PK so I used:
pattern2 = re.compile('\nPRIMARY KEY\n(.*?)\nUSING', flags=re.MULTILINE)
x=re.findall(pattern2,text)
        print(x)
but all I got was empty set [ ]. Can you suggest what did I do wrong?